# What query can i use to get me the desired results in this example

Tags: oracle-12c

[This screenshot shows the results of my first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeuTf.png) when I run this query to get a correct count of active_flag using  `

```
select distinct act_flag, empid, emplmnt_date 
from mytable;
```

it give me the correct values that I am expecting. However when I use

```
Select count(distinct act_flag), empid, emplmnt_date 
from mytable 
group by empid, emplmnt_date;
```

. The active flag counts are incorrect.

Comment: The first query does not return any count. So what result do you expect? Post an example.

Comment: I expect something like this:     Act_flag    empid
                                                2              1234
                                                3             6754

Comment: That still does not explain clear how the first query returns counts. Distinct just removes duplicates.

Comment: It removes the dups and returns what i would expect if i ran count distinct but when i run count distinct it gives me wrong count.

Comment: *The active flag counts are incorrect* It can be correct only if inactive value is NULL one.

Comment: Is there a way to upload screenshot of my results of the two queries so i can demonstrate my results set?

Comment: I have uploaded a screemshot showing my results for query 1 the one that i am doing select distinct

Comment: It would be much better if you posted the table contents as **text. not image**. And also post the wanted output.

Comment: Basically what i want as output is such  that when i do select count distinct Act_flag, empid from mytable when empid =123 my results should look like act 2 empid 123

Comment: table contents as text? are you meaning a copy and past kind of deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DISTINCT" is a Red Flag for me.
It suggests *duplication* in the data that should not be there in the first place or, sometimes, a misunderstanding of the data structure, which may have *another* key field that you're not aware of.

Performance-wise ...

```
select distinct a, b, c ...
```

... can be as "bad" as ...

```
select   a, b, c ... 
group by a, b, c 
order by a, b, c
```

Look into why you "need" the "distinct" clause in there.

This query *does* looks a mite strange:

```
select count(distinct act_flag) empid 
, emplmnt_date 
from my table 
group by empid 
, emplmnt_date
```

You're selecting a count of distinct, act_flag values, *aliased as* "empid", plus the emplymnt_date field, then grouping these results based on the "empid"-aliased value and employment date.  You also appear to be selecting from a table called "my", *aliased as* "table".  *Very* odd.

I'd expect something more like:

```
select empid 
, emplmnt_date 
, count( distinct act_flag ) c 
from my 
group by empid 
, emplmnt_date 
order by empid 
, emplmnt_date
```

Comment: I need the distinct because my fact table has some extra rows which causes act_flag to have unwanted extra counts. Your last query pretty much gives me the same results as my query number 1